# infinite scroll for my html sturcture

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
<div class="grid" style="width: 259px; left: 0px; top: 8px; position: absolute;">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" style="transform: scale(1);">
<div class="PostCrd_Snipet" style="display: block;">ii</div></div>
</div>
```

I am now splitting my ajax requesting into 15  items each.. First time 15 then 30 and so on.. Now i want to fire the ajax using scroll

Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.scroll()` might help if you are using Jquery

```
$("selector").scroll(function(){
$.ajax(); // fire ajax here
});
```